# Problems with serial communication on Arduino UNO R3

Tags: serial-port, arduino

Trying this on a Windows 7 64 Bit machine. First i plugged in the Arduino board to the PC with a usb cable. This gives me a steady light from the L and ON LEDs.

Windows began installing some drivers automaticly. When done i checked the device manager and noticed the device was recognized as "USB-SERIAL CH340 (COM3)" and windows states "This device is working properly."

Then i ran the Arduino IDE. Selected Files->Examples->01.Basics->Blink.
Checked Tools->Board->Arduino UNO and Tools->Port->COM3.

If i then compile and upload i get the following message after a long wait period:

```
Problem uploading to board.  See http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#upload for suggestions.
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xc1
```

At this point i have tried an older version of the Arduino software. Two other PC's (one of them running Win10) and i did a loopback test but nothing is working.. The lights ON and L are always lit continously when the USB cable is plugged in. TX light never even blinks or anything. Also should i be able to use the reset button ? It does nothing at all .. I would think that i would at least be able to see the LEDs flash or something ?

Comment: It seems a driver problem dude. Try uninstalling the drivers and then installing from the "C:/ programs data / arduino / drivers" (or whatever you have installed the program) I'm a linux user sorry for that path.

Comment: Already tried that. Windows tells me that there are no suitable drivers in there

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/windows#toc4 The fact that your Arduino shows up as USB-SERIAL CH340 is probably a sign that you haven't installed the proper drivers.

Comment: I have followed that guide.. Nonetheless if i try and select the "C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\Drivers" windows does not recognize them as suitable for the device.. If i force it to install anyway, i get an error code 10 that the device cannot start

Comment: Please check your configuration in the arduino IDE: 
* tools → programmer = AVRISP mkll
* board → arduino UNO

Comment: Checked, and set as you write

Comment: Try downloading the newest Arduino IDE. It will have all of the drivers in the non-admin zip file.